# Is it possible to use localStorage in HTMLService?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to use `localStroage` in `HtmlService` of Google Apps Script?
I tried below code but it show error message as localStorage is not defined.

```
function doGet() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('main');
  return ui;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>localStorage.setItem('howGood', 'awesome');</script>
  </head>
<body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't try localStorage myself yet but you could use server-side ScriptDB [1] instead - that works fine.


[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Local storage is now supported in `IFRAME` sandbox mode:

```
function doGet() {
     return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
        .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

<script>
    localStorage.setItem("mynote", "test msg");
    var note = localStorage.getItem("mynote");
    alert(note);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

localStorage is a part of HTML 5 which isn't supported by Apps Script. 
If you look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service#CreatingHTML) , it says Apps Script currently supports HTML 4.01.

However, you can open an enhancement request in the [Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) to request for this feature.

As an alternative, you can use UserProperties or CacheService for your requirements.

Comment: The bolded statement part `localStorage is a part of HTML 5 which **isn't supported by Apps Script.**` is not correct. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service#Caja) also contains information that some features of HTML5 are supported if the browser supports them. I created a script which takes the Canvas Clock example of the [Caja playground](http://caja.appspot.com/), it uses the <canvas> element of HTML5. It works fine. Here are the working [script](http://goo.gl/asVRN) and [sources](http://goo.gl/28KFt).

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Hoping App script will support soon!

Answer (score 0):

localStorage is not supported. It may be supported in the future, and an issue tracker feature request is appropriate.

Comment: Thankyou! Added one [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1809)